# сравнение таблиц в postgresql

Tags: postgresql

всем добрый день, писал программу на импорт данных с excel в бд и возникла одно дополнительное свойство которое я хочу сделать через sql запрос.
есть две таблицы
[image: sheet1]

[image: sheet2]

все столбцы в таблицах имеют тип varchar.
Задача:сравнить 1 таблицу c 2-ой и если информация с 1 таблицы не совпадает со 2-ой то в столбец в которой не совпадает информация написать тип ошибки (пустая строка, не совпадает и т.д).
я пытался сделать самостоятельно этот запрос, но получилось сделать что-то такое:

```
select    
   case when b.description  is null then  'пустая строка'
        else b.description end as description          


from sheet1 a 
 ((a.description = b.description or (a.description is null and b.description is null))
        );
```

и выводит следущее:
[image: результат]
в это результате есть несколько проблем которые я не могу решить
1.строку и выбирает правильно, но даже если там что-то написано и оно не совпадает по 2-ой таблице он всё равно пишет "пустая строка".
пожалуйста помогите или подскажите как сделать этот запрос.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576

Comment: Нормально так... а где идентифицирующее поле-то? какой-нить там артикул или ещё что...